# Meu form tá dando muito problema com a parte do cadastro

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

O meu site tem os formulários de login, o formulário de cadastro e o "Recuperar minha senha"  um ao lado do outro, eu quero conectar o formulário de cadastro com o meu banco de dados, o de login eu já consegui, mas o de cadastro eu ainda não consegui, pretendo fazer um form de cadastro usando *jQuery* e *Ajax*, alguém pode me ajudar a conectar?
O nome do meu banco de dados é `klp` e o nome de minha tabela é `table`

```
<section class="containerreg">
  <h1><font color="#fb6e14">Sign Up</font></h1>
  <p id="cadastra"> </p>
  <form id="cadastra_user" method="POST" action="">
    <p><input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Complet name"></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="user" value="" placeholder="Username"></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder="E-mail"></p>
    <p><input type="password" name="senha" value="" placeholder="Password"></p>

    <button type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-primary" />Sign Up</button>
    </form>
</section>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#cadastra_user').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var formDados new FormData($(this)[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url:'http://127.0.0.1/projects/foodee/addUsuario.php',
            type:'POST',
            data:formDados,
            cache:false,
            contentType:false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(data){
                $('#cadastra').html(data);
                alert('Cadastrado com sucesso!');
            },
            dataType: 'html'
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Essa era a página de conexao para o cadastro que foi amostrado no video, mas parece que não funcionou

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tem algo faltando no vídeo? Alguém me ajuda ae por favor porque estou sem saber o que fazer para isso dar certo
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R9AY97_yvpo

---

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsGP8.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fEpJ.png)

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjhZT.png)

[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUdCH.png)

Tipo, agr até que está aparecendo que foi cadastrado (imagem 1), porém nada aparece no meu bd (imagem 2) e o negócio é que eu tenho as conexões certas no bd, tanto de cadastro quanto de login (imagens 3 e 4)... desde já, agradeço á todos que estão me ajudando e tentando me ajudar

Comment: Não entendi nada, edite sua pergunta, está muito ampla.

Comment: Poderia melhorar o texto de sua dúvida? Seu título está totalmente não específico e vejo muita sujeira em seu texto. E o seu código não está devidamente marcado como código pelo markdown (dica, seleciona o trecho de código e pressione `ctrl+k`)

Comment: Pela segunda foto pude observar que não estás declarando as variaveis, pode ser que o formulario que voce criou está com os inputs de mesmo nome que o do de cadastro, ex: no primeiro form(login) tem input com o name="usuario" e no form de cadastro tem um input com o mesmo nome, ele está pegando o valor do primeiro formulario

Comment: Mas tipo, se não forem usados inputs de mesmo nome tanto no cadastro quanto no login, não terá como registrar as informações nos lugares certos

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda pessoal

Comment: eu quero conectar o formulário de cadastro com o meu banco de dados, o de login eu já consegui, pretendo fazer um cadastro utilizando o JQuery e Ajax para que ao clicar no botão "Inscrever-se", a página não prcise recarregar.
Como o Anderson Henrique disse, o problema para a mensagem de cadastro estava no script do java, porém, mesmo aparecendo a mensagem de cadastro do cliente, as informações não são inseridas na minha tabela (table) do meu banco de dados (klp), se quiserem ver os prints dos códigos, eu coloquei ali embaixo para se alguém tiver qualquer dúvida sobre os códigos... obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Experimente fazer assim, está faltando um igual no new FormData e na url, como está no mesmo local somente coloque o nome do documento, comentei de uma olhada

```
<section class="containerreg">
      <h1><font color="#fb6e14">Sign Up</font></h1>
      <p id="cadastra"> </p>
      <form id="cadastra_user" method="POST" action="">
        <p><input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Complet name"></p>
        <p><input type="text" name="user" value="" placeholder="Username"></p>
        <p><input type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder="E-mail"></p>
        <p><input type="password" name="senha" value="" placeholder="Password"></p>

        <button type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-primary" />Sign Up</button>
        </form>
    </section>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#cadastra_user').submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();

            //AQUI FALTA UM IGUAL var formDados = new FormData($(this)[0]);

            var formDados = new FormData($(this)[0]);
            $.ajax({

                //Como está no mesmo local você poderia fazer assim somente 
                //deixar o nome do documento

                url:'addUsuario.php',
                type:'POST',
                data:formDados,
                cache:false,
                contentType:false,
                processData:false,
                success: function(data){
                    $('#cadastra').html(data);
                    alert('Cadastrado com sucesso!');
                },
                dataType: 'html'
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
```